# jQuery getting/changing complete href details

Tags: jquery

all

Firstly is what I am trying to do:
I have one large image and set of thumbnails. Each image (big and small) is wraped in a  so that user can click on it to go to relevant resource. What I want to do is to change details of large image when I hover over thumbnails.
And I want to do it using jQuery. (I am new to jQuery, so please be gentle).

The idea is to register a hoover() handler and when user hovers over thumbnail I want to copy href and link content from thumbnail to main image.

Here is what I have:

```
<a href='main_image_url' id='main_img_link'> <img src="main_image.jpg" id='main_image'>MAIN TEXT</a>

<a href='thumb_image_url' id='thumb_img_link'> <img src="thumb_image.jpg" id='main_image'>THUMB TEXT</a>

(function() {
    var main_img = $('a#main_img_link');

    $('a#thumb_img_link').hover(function(){
        console.log($(this));
        console.log($(this).href);
        main_img.href=$(this).href;
    });
})();
```

OK, firstly, this approach does not work -- link does not change on main image. 
Secondly, I am trying to figure out how to copy the content of the link (image and text). How do I access it in its entirety??????
$(this).text only gives me THUMB TEXT. 
$(this).attr() gives me error

I did the same functionality in the past without jQuery, but would like to understand how to use jQuery for those tasks.

Thanks,
Rudolf

Answer (score 1):

Didnt read to carefully but try changing

```
$(this).href
```

to

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

Oh and your document ready seems a bit odd to me, try wrapping your code in

```
$(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Sorry, missed bracket in original post (fixed now). Hoover event handler works OK.

Comment: Something is not right -- pressing ENTER key to go to new line posts the message, so here goes all in one line. Sorry, missed bracket in original post (fixed now). Hoover event handler works OK. Use of attr() causes an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object <address href refers to> has no method 'attr'. It appears that $(this).attr() for some reason only accesses the href part of a link, not the complete thing.